# Init UseState value from UseContext value

Tags: reactjs

I have context and state variables. My state variable is initialized with my context variable. When I **update** my context in another component for exemple: changing the player's action (attack to defend), **state** variable keep the previous value.

```
const [player,setPlayer] = useContext(PlayerContext);
const [action, setAction] = useState(player.action); 

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(action); // => attack
    console.log(player.action); // => defend
});
```

This must surely be a rendering problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `action` state variable to reflect updates to `player.action`, you need make sure your dependency array (the second parameter to `useEffect`) includes `player.action` (so that it only runs when the value changes), and then call `setAction` explicitly:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (player.action !== action) {
      setAction(player.action);
   }
}, [player.action])
```

The React documentation has an extensive guide on [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) that might be helpful, along with the [`useEffect` hook API reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: I had this trick in mind but I didn't think to put player.action as a dependency of useEffect ! @Donut

Answer (score 1):

Your context state is changed somewhere after your component is rendered. Therefore the component state is not in sync with the context state anymore. With your browsers debugger you can check this behaviour and find out where it is changed.

As a general rule you should avoid adding a component state, when it shall only mirror a context‘s state, consume the context directly inside your component.